# System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.0.0

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

From which Nuget can I get System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.0.0 ?
I`ve tried the nugget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2", but the System.Net.Http.Formatting there has a verison 4.0.0.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.2 includes System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.2.0.

Whilst the NuGet package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.0 has System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282558/system-net-http-formatting-formurlencodedmediatypeformatter-error).

Comment: If you use package manager console you can pick versions of [this package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client) via: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 5.2.2`